# Loop Through Data with Sequential Time Lags output Linear Regression Coefficients

Tags: r

I have a dataset like so:

```
 set.seed(242)
 df<- data.frame(month=order(seq(1,20,1),decreasing=TRUE), 
 psit=sample(1:100,20,replace=TRUE),  var=sample(1:10,20, 
 replace=TRUE))
```

I wish to do a crude time lag analysis to see how lagged `var` data  affects `psit` data. A lag, as defined in this crude analysis, is `var` data T-1, T-2, T-3, etc. months in the past from each `psit` data point.

To see how the prior months `var` data affects `psit` data, I wish to make a  `timelag` vector which consists of `var` data that is one month offset from the `psit` variable.  Then I'll cbind the  `timelag` vector to the `psit` vector. Here is are examples of the dataframes for a 1 month offset,2 month offset,3 month offset, respectivley:

```
 set.seed(242)
 timelag1<- cbind(df[1:12,2], df[2:13,3]) #1 month time lag
 timelag2<- cbind(df[1:12,2], df[3:14,3]) #2 month time lag
 timelag3<- cbind(df[1:12,2], df[4:15,3]) #3 month time lag
```

For each dataframe, I want to regress `var` against `psit` data using the  `lm()` function and output the R-squared value. This process would be repeated for each subsequent offset. Example below:

```
 model1<-lm(timelag1)
 summary(model1)$r.squared
 model2<-lm(timelag2)
 summary(model2)$r.squared
 model3<-lm(timelag3)
 summary(model3)$r.squared
```

I would like to create a loop that iterates this process for a large dataset of 240 months. Then runs an `lm()` on each dataframe and then output the r-squared value.

Answer (score 0):

Try the dyn package which allows `lm` to process zoo and other time series objects:

```
library(dyn)

z <- read.zoo(df)
models <- lapply(1:3, function(i) dyn$lm(psit ~ lag(var, -i), tail(z, 12+i)))
sapply(models, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)
## [1] 0.31209189 0.04923393 0.09995727
```

Note that typically if one uses lag k then one also includes all smaller values of k as well.  In that case:

```
models <- lapply(1:3, function(i) dyn$lm(psit ~ lag(var, -(1:i)), tail(z, 12+i)))
do.call("anova", models)
```

giving:

```
Model 1: psit ~ lag(var, -(1:i))
Model 2: psit ~ lag(var, -(1:i))
Model 3: psit ~ lag(var, -(1:i))
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     10 8688.5                           
2      9 8221.7  1    466.73 0.4545 0.5192
3      8 8215.5  1      6.24 0.0061 0.9398
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @G. Grothendieck. I am getting an error for both options you present. `Error in lag(var, -(1:i)) : n must be a single positive integer ` . Are you able to annotate the code so I understand what the arguments do to help attain the outcome?

Comment: I should note, when I read in df using `read.zoo()`, the `month` column was removed and df only consisted of `psit` and `var` variables. Should this have happened?

Comment: Specifically, what does `tail(z, 12+i)` do in the `dyn` argument and what does `1:3`  do in the `lapply` command? In my example I had 3 models to fun the regression, but if my dataset can iterate to 12 months lag or more, is the 1:3 limiting the analysis to three lags and thus, three models?

Comment: You will need to read up on zoo. There are several vignettes. `tail(z, 12+i)` takes the 12+i most recent points.  The `lapply` runs the anonymous function for each value of 1:3 so it  is invoked three times, once for i=1, once for i=2 and then once for i=3.  If you make sure that dyn and its dependencies are installed, start a fresh R session, copy and paste `df` from the question and then copy and paste the code in the answer I see no errors.

Comment: Are you able to assist me with this updated version of my question?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395927/time-lag-analysis-on-list-of-imputed-datasets

Comment: What if `var` in the example above is a number not an integer? I am getting an error with my real data: `Error in lag(var, -i) : n must be a single positive integer` , where variances `var` can be decimals

Comment: Suspect you may have some other package loadeed that has redefined `lag`.  Try again in a fresh R session.