# Time lag analysis on list of imputed datasets

Tags: r, time-series, r-mice

My question and data is similar to the post in: [Loop Through Data with Sequential Time Lags output Linear Regression Coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266078/loop-through-data-with-sequential-time-lags-output-linear-regression-coefficient)

```
set.seed(242)
df<- data.frame(month=order(seq(1,248,1),decreasing=TRUE), 
psit=c(79,1, NA, 69, 66, 77, 76, 93,  NA, 65 ,NA ,3, 45, 64, 88, 88 
,76, NA, NA, 85,sample(1:10,228, replace=TRUE)),var=sample(1:10,248, 
replace=TRUE))
```

However, the structure of my dataset differs because I have imputed missing values for `psit`. Now `psit`, `month` and `var` are now nested within a list `tempdata` after using the `mice()` function to impute values. Now `tempdata` includes 40 new imputed datasets.

```
tempdata<-mice(data = df, m = 40, method = "pmm", maxit 
 = 50, seed = 500)
```

I want to take the 40 imputed datasets, run the same time lag analysis on each imputed dataset (this differs from the post above where there was one dataset to preform the time lag analysis) and pool the R-squared values of each like time lag among all imputed datasets.

Posts on `mice` indicate you can pool the results of a `lm()` using:

```
modelFit1 <- with(tempdata,lm(psit~ month))
summary(pool(modelFit1))
```

However, I want to pool the  R-squared values for like time lags among all 40 imputed datasets. So I am unsure how to use the `dyn$lm()` function on each imputed dataset in `tempdata` and then use the `pool()` function to pool results for the squared values.

To achieve that result. I have tried the following but get an error:

```
modelFit1 <- with(tempData, lapply(1:236, function(i) dyn$lm(psit ~ 
             lag(var, -i),tail(z, 12+i))))
summary(pool(modelFit1),function(x) summary(x)$r.squared))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using mice package, wouldn't "pool.r.squared" works for your purpose?

```
pool.r.squared(modelFit1, adjusted = FALSE)
# est      lo 95    hi 95       fmi
# R^2 0.1345633 0.06061036 0.226836 0.1195257
```

Comment: There should be a vector of R-squared values returned. I need to run a series of time lags regressions (t-1, t-2, t-3... months) on each imputed data set using `dyn$lm(psit ~ lag(var, -i),tail(z, 12+i))))`.  Then pool the r-squared for t-1 on all imputed data sets, and then pool the r-squared for t-2 lag on all imputed data sets and so on. So I would have a vector of pooled r-squared for each time lag regression.